# Django filter by date range but exclude the year

Tags: python, django, date-range

I know that if I want to filter results by date range, I just use something like

```
Sample.objects.filter(birthday__range=(start_date, end_date))
```

But how would I filter by a date range that excludes the year?

Comment: Imagine that the `start_date` is december 2020, and `end_date` is august 2021, does that mean every date between december and august, and so only leaving september, october and november out?

Comment: Yes. For example, how you would see if a user's birthday fell in the last month or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both filter and exclude. Filter as you done, and then exclude the year, like 2021

```
Sample.objects.filter(birthday__range=(start_date, end_date)).exclude(birthday_date__year=2021)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can work with a range of datetimes with:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db.models import Q

def filter_query(start_date, end_date):
    a = am, ad = start_date.month, start_date.day
    b = bm, bd = end_date.month, end_date.day
    end_date2 = end_date + timedelta(days=1)
    c = end_date2.month, end_date2.day
    if c == (2, 29) and a == (3, 1):
        return ~Q(birthday__month=2, birthday__day__gt=28)
    if a == c:
        return Q()
    if a <= b:
        if am == bm:
            return Q(birthday__month=am, birthday__day__range=(ad, bd))
        else:
            return (Q(birthday__month=am, birthday__day__gte=ad) |
                    Q(month__range=(am+1, bm-1)) |
                    Q(birthday__month=bm, birthday__day__lte=bd))
    else:
        return ~filter_query(end_date+timedelta(days=1), start_date-timedelta(days=1))
```

This will return a `Q` object that then can be used by filtering the queryset, for example:

```
Sample.objects.filter(filter_query(date(2020, 12, 15), date(2021, 1, 16)))
```

There are basically five cases:

- if the `end_date` is February 28th, and the start date is March 1st, then we exclude February 29th.
- if the `end_date` plus one day is the same as the start date, then we do not have to filter;
- if the `start_date` is less than the `end_date` and the months match, then we filter on that month, and a range check on the days;
- if the `start_date` is less than the `end_date` and the months do not match, then we look for the ranges:

  - items with the same month `start_date` and with a day greater than the month of the `start_date`;
  - items with a month between the next month of the `start_date` and less than the previous month of the `end_date`; and
  - items with the same month as the `end_date` and a day less than or equal to the day of the `end_date`.
- if the end date is less than the start date, then we return a negation of the `end_date` plus one day, and the `start_date` minus one day.